# Create an array of JSX elements? Access child component state from parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to React and I'm trying out functional components. This might be a multifaceted question but here it goes:

I have a parent component and a child component. I made an array with useState that contains the values which each of the child component gets initialized with.

Example of this:

```
function ParentComponent() {

    const [optionInputArr, setOptionInputArr] = useState < IOptionInput[] > (initialOptions);
     

return (
<div>
   {
      optionInputArr.map((item) => {
        return <OptionInput optionInput = {
          item
        }
        key = {
          item.key
        }
        />
      })
    }

</div>
)

}
```

Everything renders nicely but I now have a use-case that I need to access the value of the input field in QuestionInput component.

Child Component:

```
function OptionInput(props: {optionInput: IOptionInput}){


    return (
        <>        
        <input></input>
        </>
    );

}

export default OptionInput;
```

I thought of an idea to save the whole component in the ParentComponent as an array like so:

```
const[optionInputArr2, setOptionInputArr2] = useState<typeof OptionInput[]>([]);
```

I'm now trying to initialize a set of these components in the ParentComponent like so:

```
const initializeElems = ()=>{


     let props = {optionInput: {
            name: "",
            key: "",
            className: "",
            type: "",
            placeholder: ""
        }}


     let option1 = OptionInput(props);
        option1.key = props.optionInput.key; 


    setOptionInputArr2(option1);  // <-- results in Error

}
```

Error:

> Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'SetStateAction<((props: { optionInput: IOptionInput; }) =>
> Element)[]>'.ts(2345)

I am doing something wrong for sure but I am not exactly sure what.

I also tried to create the component like so:

```
    let elem = React.createElement("OptionInput",props); 
setOptionInputArr2(elem); // <---- results in an Error
```

This also doesn't seem to be working.

> Argument of type 'ReactElement<{ optionInput: { name: string; key:
> string; className: string; type: string; placeholder: string; }; },
> string | JSXElementConstructor>' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'SetStateAction<((props: { optionInput: IOptionInput; }) =>
> Element)

I don't know if it is only me but the errors are quite confusing to me. The functionality I am looking for is basically this:

1. Have a parent component that can access each child component state
2. Child component contains its own state

Am I thinking about this wrong?

Edit 1: I think I am supposed to use UseRef() hook to do this, I am not yet sure but I think this way I can access the child component.

Answer (score 1):

**Why do you need to store components in State?**

It's better to store component states. Let's say you want to create multiple input fields from a parent element

```
 const initialState= [
        {optionInput: {
            name: "",
            key: "",
            className: "",
            type: "",
            placeholder: "",
            value: '' //default value, this field has to be initialized
        }},
       {optionInput: {
            name: "",
            key: "",
            className: "",
            type: "",
            placeholder: "",
            value: '' //default value, this field has to be initialized
        }}] 

const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(initialState)
const updateInput = (index, data)=>{
     let newInputsState = [...inputs]
     newInputsState[index] = {...newInputsState[index], ...data}
     setInputs(newInputsState)
}


return <ChildComponent inputs={inputs} updateInput={updateInput}/>
```

**ChildComponent**

```
const ChildComponent = ({inputs, updateInput})=> inputs.map((inputProps, index)=>
        <OptionInput 
               {...inputProps} 
               key={index} 
               onChange={(e)=>
                    updateInput(index,{value: e.target.value})
               }
         />)
```

Now you can manipulate `inputs`  state from parent

Comment: How do you then access the values of these inputs from the parent? Also isn't it a better idea to store the state in the child component and not in the parent?

Comment: No, it is not better to store the state in the child.  Read the React docs on [lifting state up](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components).

Comment: @sander I wrote an example function, happy coding